# "ImportError: No module named pywintypes"

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, importerror, python-module

**After installing the module "win32" and then importing pythoncom I got the error listed above. Any idea why this is happening?**

I got this message after install : **close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr**

The installation directory: **C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages**

Comment: You're going to give more information than just that. How did you install it. Where are you running it from? Show the full stacktrace.

Comment: I downloaded pywin for 2.7 off sourcefourge. The installation directory was: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\

Comment: Forgot to mention there was message post install :***close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr***

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with this critical information.

Comment: done and done. So any idea what's happening and how I can fix?

Comment: None. I don't use Windows. I'm just making sure your question is more complete, so that if someone reads this they have more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It means that win32 is not installed, try to install it again